# How to get LatLng of Touch on Leaflet

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet

I'd like to get the LatLng of the touchpoint in a touchmove event (leaflet map). I didn't find a way to solve this. Are there any ways to get the coordinates?

```
$(document).on('touchmove', '#mapid', function(e) {
  //here i want to get the LatLng coordinates
)};
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two approaches.

One is to use Leaflet's event handling, y doing something like `map.on('mousemove', function(ev){ ... });`.

That event handler will receive a Leaflet 'MouseEvent', which includes the `LngLat` of the point of the map where the event took place. See http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.1.0.html#map-event and http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.1.0.html#mouseevent. And yes, Leaflet listens to `TouchEvent`s and `PointerEvent`s when told to listen to `MouseEvent`s.

The other approach is to use the [map's `containerPointToLatLng()` conversion method](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.1.0.html#map-containerpointtolatlng), or the [`mouseEventToLatLng()` method](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.1.0.html#map-mouseeventtolatlng) to turn a pixel coordinate or a mouse event into a `LatLng`.

Comment: the Leaflet LatLng methods of a mouse event don't work for touches on a real mobile device